# How do I shift still images to fit exactly so I can create a timelapse movie?

Tags: photo-editing, timelapse, video, auto-alignment

I want to make a time lapse film with my 365 handheld photos of nature in a year :) Therefore, I have to assemble the photos, which many free video editor programs can do.

But how do I do an exact overlay adjustment of the images? Are there programs where I can adjust the x and y axes and move each image to fit to a master photo? Also, it would be cool if the software can help correct and adjust the angle and rotate them, so specific points fit to the same points on the first master photo.

Perhaps this would be solvable by scripts or a filter in graphic programs: 3 points are to set on the master image and on all following photos you have to click also these 3 points.  The app script would then automatically process each photo to fit to the master image :)

E.g., handheld photos from a house with trees over a year could be shifted over each other exactly and the timelapse film would have no stutters. :)

Comment: Please search the [tag:timelapse] tag; there are several questions about this already. For example: [Which software to assemble a time-lapse from images?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/1254), [What software could I use for aligning time lapse stills to remove camera shake?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/7642), [How do I create a timelapse video from a collection of photographs in Linux?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/21089)

Answer (score 0):

This is a Video question. The answer is video stabilization. Tools like Davinci Resolve and Blender (Both free and excellent quality) have it.

You can do it by running an automatic method or manually. If done manually look for a feature called onion skin, with lets you see semi-transparent layers of the different frames.

You can also import them in Photoshop or Gimp and play with transparency on the layers.

But that is assuming the changes are only regarding rotation or framing (X-Y) and not perspective changes.

If it is about perspective or some other distortions you need software that allows you to "Pin" sections and deform and stretch some other sections.

I will probably edit this answer When I remember which software does that. I believe it was one for making (aligning) Hdri Images.

Answer (score 0):

### Manual solution

Warning: if hand-held, this may be more than a shift+scale+rotate. If the camera axis isn't the same you may also have to apply a perspective transform.

On Gimp, two ways:

#### The [Unified transform tool](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-unified-transform.html).

- Move one picture over the other so that some identifiable point coincides on both pictures.
- Drag the center of the tool (cross hair) to that position
- Use the Rotate/scale controls so that another point coincides.
- If needed you can try to also apply perspective correction, but finding how to control all four parameters is going to be very fiddly.

#### The `ofn-layer-aligner` script

Script is [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/). See installation instructions at the bottom of the page.

Then:

- Create a path with two anchors positioned on two identifiable points on the reference picture
- Add two points to that path, positioned on the two matching points in the picture you want to move
- Call the script to rotate/scale the layer
- For more images you can re-use the same path and only move the last two points.

There is also  [this script](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Perspective-transform-revisited) that works along the same principle but also does the perspective, using 4 points per image.

### More automatic solution

The Hugin panorama tools has an "Align stack" function.